# How to login to a Facebook account and retrieve as much as possible more information of that user

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework

After login, how can I get more information of that profile to store in my database for future cross-check and validations?

I) This is how my site logs in to Facebook user account:

```
require_once ‘facebook-platform/php/facebook.php’;
$appapikey = ‘_____________HIDDEN_____________′;
$appsecret = ’_____________HIDDEN_____________′;
$appcallbackurl = ‘exmaple.com’;
$facebook = array(
  ‘appapikey’ => $appapikey,
  ‘appsecret’ => $appsecret,
  ‘appcallbackurl’ => $appcallbackurl
);
require_once “Zend/Loader.php”;
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set(‘facebook’,$facebook);
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
$frontController->setControllerDirectory(‘/application/controllers’);
$frontController->dispatch();
```

II) Now I need this user's details, such as the photo, date of birth, lastname, firstname, URL of the Facebook, etc. How?

**Follow up:**

- https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Your AppId and AppKey is something you should hide for others, atleast the key. This is something that is supposed to be kept private, so I think you'll need to renew your key now.

To the point: I'm not familiar with the Zend Framework, but I've used the PHP SDK. If the user hasn't logged in you can use the getLoginUrl()-method from the PHP SDK to get the loginurl for the user.

If you want to retrieve information about the user you can use the api()-method to query the Graph API. Here's an example on how you can use it:

```
$fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID', 'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'));
try {
    $fb_userid = $fb->getUser();
    if($database->checkIfUserExists($fb_userid) === false) {
        $user = $fb->api('/me','GET');
        $fb_firstname = $user['first_name'];
        $fb_lastname = $user['last_name'];
        $fb_email = $user['email'];
    }
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // do something
}
```

Remember that basic information like realname, userid, username and picture are available without asking for more permissions. If you want information like the user email, you have to ask for that permission.

Take a look at the documentation below to look what information you can get from the user-object.

- Documentation - PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
- Documentation - Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/